# Spring Data Rest Mongo - how to create a DBRef using an id instead of a URI?

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I have the following entity, that references another entity.

```
class Foo {
    String id;
    String name supplierName;
    **@DBRef** TemplateSchema templateSchema;
...
}
```

I want to be able to use the following JSON (or similar) to create a new entity.

```
{
    "supplierName": "Stormkind",
    "templateSchema": "572878138b749120341e6cbf"
}
```

...but it looks like Spring forces you to use a URI like this:

```
{
    "supplierName": "Stormkind",
    "templateSchema": "/template-schema/572878138b749120341e6cbf"
}
```

Is there a way to create the DBRef by posting an ID instead of a URI?

Thanks!

Comment: You can implement a custom deserializer for DBRef, but as Oliver Gierke points out, REST resources should be identified by their URI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In REST, the only form of ID's that exist are URIs (hence the name Unique Resource *Identifier*). Something like 572878138b749120341e6cbf does not identify a resource, `/template-schema/572878138b749120341e6cbf` does.

On the HTTP level, entities do not exist, only resources identified by URIs. That's why Spring Data REST expects you to use URIs as identifiers.